# VS2022 Paste Bug?

Tags: paste, visual-studio-2022

Recently VS2022 has been behaving unpredictably when I press ctrl-v (paste). It does not always do it, but frequently enough to be repeatable.
If I copy a section of text (ctrl-c), and then select some other text to replace when I paste it the selected text and the pasted text will disappear. A ctrl-z will return the text that WAS pasted.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Text-disappears-after-paste-in-js-file/10086754?space=8&q=paste+disappears

Comment: check this if it helps u:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72403834/visual-studio-pasting-text-into-cshtml-deletes-text